# Is it possible to do a webhook to existing Firebase endpoint?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering if it was possible on Firebase to let a third party service do a POST request to my database and to my endpoint? eg. `/broadcasts/`

The post request can't have auth on write as part of the restrictions from the third party service.

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this in Firebase?

Comment: That depends for a large part on the third-party service. Firebase's API for REST access is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen exactly what I needed